# Remove the value Binding based on the model

Tags: knockout.js

I have a model property which at times should be bind to an `input` element and sometimes to a `select` element, which is based on a configuration.
I use the value binding on both elements and hide either one using the visible binding.

As both bindings are on the page, when the `input` is visible and when I enter some text which does not exists in the hidden `select`, I am unable to change its value. So in the case that the `input` element is visible (`isDropdown` is false) I do not want the `select` to be bound (or is there some other better way to handle this?).

Sample Javascript model

```
var player = function (name, age, country, isDropdown) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.age = ko.observable(age);
    this.country = ko.observable(country);
    this.isDropdown = ko.observable(isDropdown);
};

var playerModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.myPlayer = new player('Murray', 28, 'UK', false);
    //self.myPlayer = new player('Murray', 28, 'UK', true);
    self.countryList = ['US', 'UK', 'SWISS'];   
}
var model = new playerModel();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

HTML Code

```
    Name:
<input type="text" data-bind="value: myPlayer.name" />
<br/>Age:
<input type="text" data-bind="value: myPlayer.age" />
<br/>Country:
<input type="text" data-bind="value: myPlayer.country, visible: !(myPlayer.isDropdown())" />
<select data-bind="options: $root.countryList, 
    value:myPlayer.country, 
    optionsCaption:'Choose..',        
    visible: myPlayer.isDropdown()"></select>
<br/>
(There is a dropdown / input which is hidden, please swap the commented lines in javascript model to enable that )
```

Respective JS Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/saamisolutions/h8HVt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use virtual `if` bindings instead. This prevents the databound select element from being in the DOM and bound when `isDropdown` is `false`.

```
<!-- ko ifnot: myPlayer.isDropdown -->
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: myPlayer.country" />
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: myPlayer.isDropdown -->
    <select data-bind="options: $root.countryList, 
        value:myPlayer.country, 
        optionsCaption:'Choose..'">
    </select>
<!-- /ko -->
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a46H9/1/)